# Formula Field to display 4 different dates (from different fields) in one field

Tags: formula-field, date

Looking to create a formula field that will pull 4 different dates from 4 different fields and display in one field. I put the code below, but I'm getting an error. How can I fix it?

Error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text,
>   received Date

Code:

```
Date_1__c & ", " & Date_2__c & ", " & Date_3__c & ", " & Date_4__c
```

Comment: What is the field data type you are using for formula field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert them to text first, as dates are not naturally a "text" type, which is why we're allowed to do math with dates. Using the TEXT formla should give the desired result:

```
TEXT(Date_1__c) & ", " & 
TEXT(Date_2__c) & ", " & 
TEXT(Date_3__c) & ", " & 
TEXT(Date_4__c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `+` to concat the Dates, But first you need to take Dates into Text function :

```
TEXT(Date_1__c) + ", " + TEXT(Date_2__c) + ", " + TEXT(Date_3__c) + ", " + TEXT(Date_4__c)
```